# Add a Scroll View in Navigation Drawer in Android

Tags: android, scrollview, navigation-drawer

I'm implementing a Navigation Drawer and it includes several text views list view and a edit text. And when I run it there is a scroll view only for list view (which is I didn't implement).

Here is my code.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<!-- The main content view -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<!-- The navigation drawer -->

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#FFA500">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lin1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/profPic"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_prof"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textName"
            android:textSize="20px"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textTraveller"
            android:textSize="12px"
            android:text="Traveller"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textName"
             android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/line"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textTraveller"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textRecentViewed"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Recent Viewed"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:typeface="serif"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/profPic"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textPlacesNearBy"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Places Near By"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:typeface="serif"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textRecentViewed"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/slider_list"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textPlacesNearBy"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditTextLike"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:hint="What do you like ?"
        android:background="@drawable/shape2"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_below="@+id/slider_list"
        android:textSize="15dp">
    </EditText>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

So, what I need is to add a Scroll View to my Navigation Drawer and I don't need that ghost scroll view in the list view. Tried several exmples in the internet and anything didn't work properly. So, here i put the code without any of these scroll views.

Someone please help me to make it. Thanks :)

Edit

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<!-- The main content view -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<!-- The navigation drawer -->

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#FFA500">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lin1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/profPic"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_prof"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textName"
                android:textSize="20px"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textTraveller"
                android:textSize="12px"
                android:text="Traveller"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textName"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/line"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textTraveller"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textRecentViewed"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Recent Viewed"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:typeface="serif"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/profPic"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textPlacesNearBy"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Places Near By"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:typeface="serif"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textRecentViewed"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"/>

    <!--Added these two parameters 4th & 5th-->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/slider_list"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
        android:stackFromBottom="true"

        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textPlacesNearBy"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditTextLike"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:hint="What do you like ?"
        android:background="@drawable/shape2"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_below="@+id/slider_list"
        android:textSize="15dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"/>

</LinearLayout>
<!--You didn't close drawer layout-->
```

You can see how my list view cuts because of this inner scroll. I need to remove it and add a scroll view to whole navigation bar

-Edit 2 -

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<!-- The main content view -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<!-- The navigation drawer -->
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_container"
    android:layout_below="@id/title"
    android:fillViewport="false"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#FFA500"
    android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
    android:stackFromBottom="true">



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lin1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/profPic"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_prof"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textName"
                android:textSize="20px"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textTraveller"
                android:textSize="12px"
                android:text="Traveller"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textName"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/line"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textTraveller"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textRecentViewed"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Recent Viewed"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:typeface="serif"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/profPic"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textPlacesNearBy"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Places Near By"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:typeface="serif"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textRecentViewed"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"/>


        <!--Added these two parameters 4th & 5th-->
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/slider_list"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"



            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textPlacesNearBy"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditTextLike"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:hint="What do you like ?"
        android:background="@drawable/shape2"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_below="@+id/slider_list"
        android:textSize="15dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"/>



</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
<!--You didn't close drawer layout-->
```

Comment: ListViews inside ScrollViews don't really work, since ListViews are scrollable as well, and will consume the scrolling touch events. You might move the ListView out of the ScrollView, so you'll have two separate scrolling sections in the drawer.

Comment: Your layout looks weird. You have a lot of LinearLayouts without any child Views and also no Id, so you can't add child views during runtime. Why did you set it up like that?

Comment: @Mike M., So, you mean to say that I can't add single scroll view to my Navigation Drawer? But, I've seen many Navigation drawers that has scroll views

Comment: @BenjaminScharbau , Yeah! I added different Linear layouts to add spaces between my text views etc. I don't need any child views I need a Scroll Bar that scrolls my whole navigation drawer :)

Comment: You can have a scrolling drawer. I'm just saying that putting a ListView inside a ScrollView is what's causing your problem.

Comment: So, What should I do  Mike M.?

Comment: I'm tired of trying this now. Tried almost everything to rmove this inner scroll and put a scroll to the whole drawer. Nothing works fine. :(

Answer (score 0):

try this :

**YourClassName.java**

```
package app.yakuzian.maestro.yakuzianslidingmenu;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity; 
import android.widget.ListView;

/**
 * Created by Krishnavanshi on 19-11-2015.
 */
public class YourClassName extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView list;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.youractivityname);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.slider_list);
        scrollMyList();
    }

    // to set the scroll position to the bottom of the list.
    private void scrollMyList() {
        list.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //to scroll list programatically
                list.setSelection(list.getCount()-1);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

**youractivity.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <!-- The navigation drawer -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#FFA500">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lin1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="10dp"
                android:layout_height="10dp" />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/profPic"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_prof"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="10dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textName"
                    android:textSize="20px"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textTraveller"
                    android:textSize="12px"
                    android:text="Traveller"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textName"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"/>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/line"
            android:layout_width="280dp"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textTraveller"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textRecentViewed"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Recent Viewed"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:typeface="serif"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/profPic"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textPlacesNearBy"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Places Near By"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:typeface="serif"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textRecentViewed"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"/>

        <!--Added these two parameters 4th & 5th-->
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/slider_list"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
            android:stackFromBottom="true"

            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textPlacesNearBy"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/EditTextLike"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:hint="What do you like ?"
            android:background="@drawable/shape2"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_below="@+id/slider_list"
            android:textSize="15dp"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <!--You didn't close drawer layout-->
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Have you cutomized your list view?

Comment: can you post screenshot of yourxml ?

Comment: Added. You can see how my list view cuts because of this inner scroll. I need to remove it and add a scroll view to whole navigation bar. :)

Comment: You should use `RecyclerView`. it is more advanced and flexible and efficient version of ListView. `RecyclerView ViewGroup` is an container for larger data set of views that can be recycled and scrolled very efficiently.

Comment: have you tried this too ?<ScrollView> <ListView ></ListView></ScrollView> in your xml ?

Comment: Nooo. I need to remove that inner scroll and add a scroll view to the whole screen

Comment: add properties as given in this link http://s20.postimg.org/og9ac4nv1/scrollit.jpg

Comment: Where should I put this?

Comment: I don't need this scroll view to listview. i NEED TO SCROLL THE WHOLE DRAWER. tHATS WAHT i'M TELLING FROM THE BEGINING. bUT, u JUST PUT THE SCROLL VIEW TO LIST VIEW HERE. :)

Comment: then put <ScroollView> at top and </ScrollView> at bottom

Comment: Tried before and tried now. Please look at edit 2. Didn't do anything. works like previous :(

Comment: I'm tired of trying this now. Tried almost everything to rmove this inner scroll and put a scroll to the whole drawer. Nothing works fine. :(

Comment: Hmmm. Yeah! agree with you. But, Why is it still not working though? You  have any ideawhy?

Comment: I am looking for another way ( `RecyclerView`)..When it's done, I will upload it too..You can try it too...

Comment: Okay Thanks for that. Yeah! I'm trying too :)

Comment: @Android run this example and edit menu list, there you will see navigation drawer menu in res/menu,Scroll by default nothing need to be implemented https://github.com/Dahnark/Navigation-Drawer-Android-Design-Support-Library/archive/master.zip

Comment: Okay.I'll give it a try :)

Comment: Hi, What do you mean by 'Scroll by default nothing need to be implemented' ? I can see my navigation drawer in res/menu. What should I do here?